# Finding equation of surface from known data

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I have the raw data of $X$, $Y$, $Z$, where $X$ and $Y$ are inputs and $Z$ is the output. Plotting the surface gives the red curve:[image]

The surface seems to be a simple function involving trigonometric functions. For example, plotting the equation $\cos(X)^2 + \cos(Y)^2$ gives the blue surface and it looks similar to the red graph (but the RMS error is very large).
I have tried introducing variables ($a_1\cos(X)^2 + a_2\cos(Y)^2$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ vary from $0$ to $1$) but the RMS error is still large.

How can I find the equation which gives the red surface?

Comment: Perhaps consider NURBS or B-Spline based surfaces?

Comment: If you cannot come up with other ideas (e.g., some quadratic function) and do not have prior knowledge (e.g., from physics, data generating process), I'd suggest [symbolic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression). There are Python and Julia packages available that implement this.

Comment: Most curves/surfaces do not correspond to close-form formulas. What makes you think that such a formula exists?

Comment: Are you familiar with least-squares regression? Given some candidate functions e.g., polynomials. you can find the linear combination that yields the least error over your dataset. Least squares with degree $\leq 2$ polynomials look like they should yeild a decent fit.

Comment: @cos_theta, I will try that out.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, the surface looks similar to a 2D parabola or a 2D bell curve and the quadratic cosine expression (blue surface) is somewhat aligning to the data.

Comment: @whpowell96, I used LS regression with a 2D gaussian function and I was able to find the coefficients which gave a better match than the blue surface I plotted